# Crystal Report in Blazor

Tags: crystal-reports, blazor

I want to use Crystal report in my Blazor Project.
But when I am trying to add crystal report then not showing reporting

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2):

Crystal runtime has COM dependencies. So it is compatible with .NET -- not with .NET Core.